# Only one node in ResourceManager

Tags: hadoop

It is normal that in ResourceManager (nodemanager:8088/cluster/nodes) i can see only one node?

In my test environment i setup two node cluster and command bin/hdfs dfsadmin -report show me two nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but i am find the solution.

You need to add following property in your conf/yarn-site.xml file on all nodes:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>resourcemanager_address:8030</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>resourcemanager_address:8032</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
    <value>resourcemanager_address:8088</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>resourcemanager_address:8031</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
    <value>resourcemanager_address:8033</value>
</property>
```

That will be overwrite the default settings for resourcemanager address (default is 0.0.0.0).
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply set

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>resourcemanager_address</value>
</property>
```

... and the rest of the properties will be set correctly automatically.

To point out the obvious, make sure you start/restart the nodemanager as well.

```
$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR start nodemanager
```